# How and where is x:Key implemented in MAUI?

Tags: xamarin, maui

`x:Key` behaves like an attached property where it is available in the children of `ResourceDictionary`. However, I cannot find the implementation of `x:Key` in `ResourceDictionary` ([the repo](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/50d5bc9c2aed26276371740bd9d5e5beab52533c/src/Controls/src/Core/ResourceDictionary.cs#L18)).

**Question**: How and where is `x:Key` implemented in MAUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x:Key`, along with other attributes that are part of the `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"` namespace are special **[XmlNames](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Xaml/XmlName.cs)**, that are built into the XAML parser; they are not implemented as attached properties. Basically, they are almost equivalent to keywords in C#.

You can view the static variable declarations for them here, inside the `XmlName` struct: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Xaml/XmlName.cs

For instance, the static `XmlName` field 'xKey' (`x:Key`) is referenced here in the XamlParser class: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Controls/src/Xaml/XamlParser.cs#L261

The other special XAML attributes that are implemented in the same way are:

`x:Arguments`, `x:DataType`, `x:FactoryMethod`, `x:Name`, `x:TypeArguments`.

`x:Class` and `x:FieldModifier` are also part of the `x:` namespace, but they're kind of a special case.

Edit: Should mention that if you want to create your own set of extensions that behave similarly, you can create what's called a [Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/creating). Though you can't directly add to the `x:` namespace. `x:Static` for instance is implemented as a markup extension: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml/MarkupExtensions/StaticExtension.cs